# Meaning of YouTube "-nocookie: and "rel=0" in the iframe embed code

Tags: youtube

If I copy the embed code from a YouTube video I get the code below.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/kk5xfK0ovrk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And if I select a 1280x760 size for the video and copy that embed code I get:

```
<iframe width="1280" height="720" src="//www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/kk5xfK0ovrk?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

But if I just take the original embed code and only change the width to 1280 and height to 720 I also get a perfectly good 1280x760 video. So I'm wondering what the purpose is of the "-nocookie" and the "rel=0" in the code YouTube generates for the 1280x560 case.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

YouTube's new 'nocookie' feature and Quoting from the [Youtube's Rel=0](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#rel) Documentation:

> **rel (supported players: AS3, AS2, HTML5)** Values: **0** or **1**. *Default is 1*.
>   This parameter indicates whether the player should show related videos
>   when playback of the initial video ends.
>
> But **after 25 September 2018**, you will not be able to disable related
>   videos. Instead, if the rel parameter is set to 0, related videos will
>   come from the same channel as the video that was just played.

For further information you can read through the [YouTube Embedded Players and Player Parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters) where all the parameters are listed.

Comment: As for the `-nocookie` part, it's supposed to mean that no cookies will be left in the user's browser if the *play* button hasn't been clicked; however, [not so true...](https://www.cnet.com/news/youtubes-new-nocookie-feature-continues-to-serve-cookies/)